# How to each 3 different buttons with different actions?

Tags: jquery

Well i have 3 buttons and these must have just a one class `.fdm` so how is possible every button have a different actions just calling the class?

I actually using, but like this i must set id to each button. I no want this, i wanna set just a classname and identify diff actins for all buttons.

JS:

```
jQuery(function(){
$('#r').bind('click',function(){
$('#alvo').css('background','#ff0000');
})
$('#g').bind('click',function(){
$('#alvo').css('background','#155c00');
})
$('#b').bind('click',function(){
$('#alvo').css('background','#001eff');
})
})
```

HTM:

```
<div id="alvo" style="width:200px;height:200px;border:2px #000 solid;">
</div>

<button class="fdm" type="button" id="r">R</button>
<button class="fdm" type="button" id="g">G</button>
<button class="fdm" type="button"  id="b">B</button>
```

Like i said i just wanted to use a classname to all buttons

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EGn9z/)**

Comment: What is a reason of not using `id` to do this? And why you want your buttons to have only one `class`?

Comment: this and homework form high school, diff actions for buttons havin same class without id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated the fiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/EGn9z/2/

```
$(function(){

    $ ( ".fdm" ).click( function(){
        $('#alvo').css('background', $(this).attr("data-color"));
    });

})

<div id="alvo" style="width:200px;height:200px;border:2px #000 solid;">
</div>

<button class="fdm" type="button" id="r" data-color="#ff0000">R</button>
<button class="fdm" type="button" id="g" data-color="#00ff00">G</button>
<button class="fdm" type="button" id="b" data-color="#0000ff">B</button>
```

have put the colors in data-attribute

Comment: beat me to it - this was the way I was going too!

Comment: **FYI:** `$(this).attr("data-color")` == `$(this).data("color")`

Answer (score 1):

As you can't add other classes and and cannot use `id`, you can decide about action using the `text` of the button:

```
$(function(){
  $('.fdm').bind('click',function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
    if(text  == 'R')
        $('#alvo').css('background','#ff0000');
    if(text  == 'G')
        $('#alvo').css('background','#155c00');
    if(text  == 'B')
        $('#alvo').css('background','#001eff');
  }) ;    

});
```